# Is recommending operating systems allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

Some voted to close [Desktop Linux distribution with the latest GNOME 3?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14/gnome-3-which-linux-distros-are-reliable-and-bug-free) with the following reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Linux distribution and not about software

I'm pretty sure Linux distributions are software :)

Comment: You need to link to [the question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14/gnome-3-which-linux-distros-are-reliable-and-bug-free), and also mention this meta thread in a comment on the question.

Comment: Can we make this a more general question about Operating Systems?

Comment: Nevermind, this one has been edited to fill the need for the separate question.

Comment: Another sample: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/253/linux-based-distributions-dedicated-to-video-editing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed, a Linux distribution is software.

“[This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Linux distribution and not about software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14/gnome-3-which-linux-distros-are-reliable-and-bug-free#comment50_14)” doesn't make sense.

[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14/gnome-3-which-linux-distros-are-reliable-and-bug-free) is very opinion-based (“good community support” is not an objective criterion, and “excellent support” is inviting debate). But it is definitely not *off-topic*.

Let me stress however that on-topic does not imply good. In my experience, questions asking for a Linux distribution tend to be underspecified. You can run almost any Linux application on almost any Linux distribution (in a given category, i.e. general-purpose or appliance). If you ask about a Linux distribution, make sure to explain why it makes a difference, why you can't just take any of the major distributions and install whatever software you need.

Comment: I agree with this 100% - it's silly to think that Linux Distributions are not software.

Comment: @dotVezz Maybe my statement was to quick, but I'd rather see these kind of question off topic on this site. Good to have a meta-discussion about that.

Comment: Full ack from me. There are very specialized distros e.g. for education, children, multi-media, maintenance, ... So questions like "Linux-distro suitable for children" would IMHO be a perfect on-topic question on our site.

Answer (score 0):

Is this OS question on-topic?

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/linux-distro-alternative-to-xp-for-web-development-company

Major requirements are about the ability of running some software (OP just need to have a look on editor's download page to see if Linux is supported), and as Gille writes:

> You can run almost any Linux application on almost any Linux distribution

Comment: Almost is not always and this can be very hard. For example is not easy to install *deb* application on RPM based system.

Comment: @MariuszS An application isn't “deb”. A package may be “deb”. The application itself will also install on non-deb-based distribution.

Comment: Yes, this question (as it is now) suffers from the same defect as many questions about choosing a Linux distribution: any will work equally well. It isn't off-topic, but it is incomplete.

Answer (score -4):

I'm gonna pitch in with this site is intended for single-use applications, such as Microsoft Word is designed for editing documents, it is not designed for editing photographs or movies. In the same vein, a developer oriented gui merge tool does not create CD-Rom images.

In this sense, a Linux distro is actively a thing of research and passion, as well as platform alignment, but it is in no sense a single-use application. Indeed, the mere fact that there are many ways to configure a given distro (think Ubuntu vs Kubuntu) and still retain the core commonality should be evidence that this will be a tricky question to answer.

I vote that it is not appropriate for this site, as that is too wide ranging.

Comment: As a user, I want to use a distro with a default configuration that best meets my needs. I dont want to reconfigure all things manually to make from distro X distro Y.

Comment: Wait, does this mean I'm not allowed to answer “Emacs”?

Comment: @Gilles has a good (also entertaining) point.

Comment: Also, questions like "Linux distro for children" or "Linux Live-Distro for maintenance" are IMHO very fitting questions on our site.