# Are kernel side software recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

From a user perspective a kernel-side software isn't as different as userland ones *(on windows, you launch `.sys` instead of `.exe`)*.

But it appears questions about finding a particular filesystem or choosing utilities for forcing to delete files or choosing the best scheduler related to a specific configuration got closed as not related to software recommendations. On some OS those kind of questions use userland programs *(they still use privileged CPU ring)*.

So are questions about programs which run at kernel-side/[privileged CPU ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) on-topic on SR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kernel-side software is on-topic just like user-side. For that matter, [operating system recommendations are on-topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-recommending-operating-systems-allowed-on-this-site) (even if it's hard to write a [good one](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)).

I don't know why you perceive that questions related to kernel-side software get closed as off-topic, since you didn't post links.

- A question asking for a driver for a specific filesystem would be on-topic. So would a question leaving the filesystem open; you would have to describe the use case precisely enough to explain why you can't use just any filesystem, but that's par for the course.
- “Utilities for forcing to delete files” should be on-topic but you'll need to explain what “forcing to delete files” means (ways to hit the user with a stick if they refuse to delete files are off-topic because they would be hardware recommendations).
- “Choosing the best scheduler” sounds like it's asking about configuring a scheduler that you have, rather than installing a new one (which is rarely possible as schedulers tend to be built deep inside OSes). Configuring software that you have is off-topic here, but on the off chance that you do mean a piece of software that you can install, that would be on-topic.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16830/2341 as example...

Comment: @user2284570 This question is partly a question on the deliberations of the SD card associations (which is completely off-topic), partly a question about the features of exFAT (off-topic and too broad and vague for Stack Exchange but could be a topic for a discussion forum or a chat conversation), and only slightly asking for a software recommendation (which filesystem to use on an SD card). In order to be answerable as a software recommendation question, you need to explain [what you use it for](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336). What criteria are important in your FS choice?

Comment: Plus, "chosing the best X" (at least without context) rather sounds like being either "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" – specifically if it would end up as a list of names (not enough criteria given). If, OTOH, there were a clear use-case described in a fully comprehensible way to encourage *specific* recommendations, it were on-topic (as a general rule, never ask "what is the best X" unless you expect us recommending the "worst X" otherwise – which would defeat the purpose of this site ;)